# How to deploy artifact to github releases using TeamCity

Tags: github, deployment, teamcity, artifact

I configured TeamCity to pull and build my github repo. Than it creates .zip artifact with files that are in "bin/Debug" folder. After that I want it to create a new tag with build number and push it to github releases, but don't have any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After research i finally found the answer.

1. *Install [github-release](https://github.com/aktau/github-release) on the TeamCity build agent server(s)*. To
   install github-release get the latest release and extract .exe file
   somewhere on drive (In my case C:\Program Files
   (x86)\github-release\bin\windows\amd64)
2. [Generate new security access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) on github.
3. *Create artifact after build.*
   To do it go to your build configuration and set ArtifactPaths to
   **MyProjectName\bin\Debug => DependentArtifact.zip**
4. Create second build configuration (**Not build step**) with "Deploy" Name.
5. *Add new trigger to Deploy configuration.*
   Triggers => Add new Trigger =>
   Finish Build Trigger => Set build configuration to your first build
   name and enable "Trigger after successful build only " checkbox
6. *Add dependent artifact to Deploy build configuration*:
   Dependencies => Add new artifactDependency. Set Depend On = to your first build configuration. Get artifacts from = Latest successful build. Artifact Rules = **DependentArtifact.zip**
7. *Add new build step to Deploy:*
   Build Steps => Add build step => CommandLine and paste following script to custom script field:

   **[PathToYourRepo]** git tag Release-v0.%build.number% 
   **[PathToYourRepo]** git push 
   **[PathToYourRepo]** git push --tags

   **[PathToGithubReleaseExe]** release --security-token **[YourSecurityToken]** --user **[YourGithubUserName]** --repo **[YourRepoName]** --tag Release-v0.%build.number%

   **[PathToGithubReleaseExe]** upload --security-token **[YourSecurityToken]** --user **[YourGithubUserName]** --repo **[YourRepoName]** --tag Release-v0.%build.number% --name Release-v0.%build.number%.zip --file DependentArtifact.zip

And that's it! Maybe there is a simpler way to do it, but I haven't found it.

Comment: Step 1 should read "Install .. on the TeamCity agent machine" as the build is executed on the agent.